# How to do a bitwise operation on some data in C?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I have the following code snippet in a C function

```
int i;
for (i = bytes; i>0; --i) {
    printf("byte: %d", data & 0xff);
    data>>= 8;
}
```

to split given data into bytes in a big endian way (`bytes` is the number bytes in `data`). The data itself could be anything - an int or a 100 byte long character string. However, if `data` it not an `int`, the code won't work (`invalid operands to binary X`).

For example, assuming `data` is a string with the content `hello world` I expect to get the following numbers:

```
byte: 104
byte: 101
byte: 108
byte: 108
byte: 111
byte: 32
byte: 119
byte: 111
byte: 114
byte: 108
byte: 100
```

I need a simple solution to wotk in pure C without any extra libraries besides the standard ones.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to print the bytes of raw binary data:

```
void print_bytes(const void *data, size_t len)
{
    const unsigned char *p = data;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i++)
        printf("%d ", p[i]);
}
```

You can call it with the address of any object, like this:

```
unsigned long long u = 1234567890;
print_bytes(&u, sizeof u); // beware of endianness!

const char *s = "hello world";
print_bytes(s, strlen(s));
```